# XSD RegEx Validation

Tags: xml, regex, xsd

I am trying to create a regular expression to validate an XML element. I am fairly new to regular expressions.

The format I'm trying to achieve is [month name][ ][day]

For example, "January 1"

Here is what I tried.

```
<xs:simpleType>
  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
    <xs:pattern value="([January]|[February]|[March]|[April]|[May]|[June]|[July]|[August]|[September]|[October]|[November]|[December])[ ]([1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|[3][0-1])"/>
  </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

The above code is not working for me. I suspect that the way I'm checking for month names is wrong. Is it possible for me to compare the value against whole strings? Or do I have to do something along the lines of value="([J][a][n][u][a][r][y]|[F][e][b]...)?

Comment: Square brackets in a regex contain a list of alternative single characters, for example [ABC] matches "A" or "B" or "C", so it's equivalent to (A|B|C).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect there are shorter forms of matching what you're looking for, but this should do the job:

`(January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December)\s?([1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\b`

You're checking for the month name, 0 or more white space characters, and then a valid day of month integer.

Here's a working example of a PCRE regex: http://regex101.com/r/cQ9nK8

Comment: One catch - it's not smart enough to invalidate months with more than the number of calendar days; you'd need to put a conditional `(condition1|condition2)` type statement in to watch for that. But, given that you're matching a date string, this should be sufficient.